# When Hover UL LI at Dropdown, How to Choose a LI as 'hovered'

Tags: jquery, css

how to select a menu item (LI) when hover parent UL?

Example:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li class="thisone">item 3
        <ul>
            <li>subMenu1</li>
            <li>subMenu2
                <ul>
                    <li>This should appear when Hover First Level Item3, would be like someone would be hovering subMenu2, but when actually hovered Item3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li>subMenu3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery (something like this)**

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $('.topmenu .thisone').hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('li:has('ul')).select();
    });
});
```

Does anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topmenu > li:has(ul)').hover(function(e){
        $(this).find('ul').toggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TAnu3/)

Comment: superb and you give quick answer everytime :)

Comment: Didn't work. I have 3 levels, when hover first level, it will show second level right? And the second level(sub) needs to show automatically the third level as default, like someone had hovered it!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.topmenu .thisone').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).closest('li:has("ul")').toggleClass('className');
    });
});
```